# How do I get my Openshift application to display my domain name in the address bar?

Tags: dns, openshift, alias, cname, domain-name

Example:

- I register a domain name called mydomain.com with GoDaddy.
- I am using a free hosting service called Openshift to host my website.
- When I visit my website the url reads myproject-myname.rhcloud.com.
- I want the url to display www.mydomain.com because I own that domain.

To get around this, Openshift says to set up an alias using CNames.

On GoDaddy I set up the CName record like this:

- host (subdomain): www
- destination:      myproject-myname.rhcloud.com

On Openshift I set up the alias like this:

- alias:       www.mydomain.com
- destination: myproject-myname.rhcloud.com

Now when you access the site using the domain name www.mydomain.com, the url at the top of my site will read www.mydomain.com and everything works just fine. But when I try to access my site using just mydomain.com it still shows the Openshift url myproject-myname.rhcloud.com.

How do I point my naked domain name to my www domain?
I want to search both mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com and end up at www.mydomain.com.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this by changing my domain's A record on GoDaddy. By using wwwizer.com I can redirect traffic from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com simply by putting their ip address in my A record.

On GoDaddy I set my A record like this:

- host: mydomain.com
- ip:   174.129.25.170

174.129.25.170 is the public ip address of wwwizer.com. When people access your site by your domain name, the request first goes to wwwizer servers and if the subdomain www isn't present, it's added on. Then your CName reccord points the www address to the actual location of your website. So in my case the process looks like this:

With www:

search www.mydomain.com -> go to server at 174.129.25.170 -> www present -> continue to www.mydomain.com -> redirect using CName to myproject-myname.rhcloud.com -> Openshift alias changes address bar to www.mydomain.com

Without www:

search mydomain.com -> go to server at 174.129.25.170 -> www not present, add www -> continue to www.mydomain.com -> redirect using CName to myproject-myname.rhcloud.com -> Openshift alias changes address bar to www.mydomain.com

And this seems to work pretty well. I just had to set up a CName and A record on GoDaddy and then set up an alias on Openshift. There's no signup required to use wwwizer servers and the service is free. If anyone has a better way to do this, please feel free to comment or submit an answer!